# How to trigger an action only after 2nd tap on mobile Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show a mobile popup after 2nd tap/touch on mobile device for once until page load. But in my code How can I fix this happen only for second click. currently it looping every second click.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/swxbne1z/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
    var clicks = true;
    $(window).bind('click', function(event){
        if (clicks) {
           clicks = false;
        } else {
          alert('Hi there! you just ckick twice');
          clicks = true;
        }
    });
   }
});
```

Comment: sorry. I don't understand your question. I remove my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did this I count click so you can change its value to when it should trigger

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {

   var count=0;
   $(document).click(function(){
       count++;
        if (count===2) {
          alert('Hi there! you just ckick twice');
          event.preventDefault();
        }
   });

   }
});
```